# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: laravel, octobercms

i got an error after OctoberCMS was installed, but i cant figure it out how to fix it.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in
>   /var/www/html/..../public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
>   on line 233

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

The sourcecode uses the coalesce operator `??` which is not available in your PHP version.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

https://github.com/laravel/framework/

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
```